# Tapping in contenteditable div fails to position cursor when running under Cordova/Phonegap

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, meteor, phonegap-plugins

I have a contenteditable div with multiple lines of text inside running on iOS and Android using Cordova.
Tapping the div the first time moves input focus to the div as expected, but after that I have a significant problem...

Normally I would expect that tapping the contenteditable div would place the cursor at (or at least very near) the place where the tap occurred.
This is certainly what happens if I simply browse to a web page containing the same contenteditable div using Mobile Safari or Android's browser.
But as soon as I run it under Cordova I find that not only does the cursor not get positioned properly when I tap around, but more often than not tapping on a contenteditable div that has input focus actually makes it lose the input focus!

It is possible to repro this with a super-simple example like this:

```
<div contenteditable="true">
    <div>line 1</div>
    <div>line 2</div>
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated.  I would be tearing my hair out, but it's a little late for that strategy... am already bald.

I am using MeteorJS, but doubt this is the cause of the problem since browsing to the web site in the regular mobile browser does not produce the issue.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 3):

It appears that the problem was caused by the inclusion of a package called Fastclick.  Once I removed it the tapping seemed to work normally.

Comment: FastClick was causing the issue for me too. Off to check their issues page and see about upgrading it.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into some weird behavior like this under iOS. Two things to try:

1. Make your contenteditable element taller. In one case, I found that the cursor could not be positioned too close to the bottom of the element, but adding a sufficient padding-bottom (experiment) would make that content "reachable".
2. Set focus on your contentEditable element on touchstart. See https://github.com/xing/wysihtml5/issues/98#issuecomment-35707207. https://gist.github.com/shimondoodkin/1081133 looks related too.

Comment: Hi - thank you for your answer!  It appears that the problem in my case was caused by a package called Fastclick.  I removed it today, and the contenteditable started behaving itself.

Comment: You probably want to just disable Fastclick for your contenteditable elements (add the class "needsclick"), otherwise you'll have an annoying click delay throughout the app.